# bash while loop that breaks at a given file size

Tags: bash, shell, control-flow

So, I bought this book called *Primes and Programming*, and it's pretty tough going. Today I wrote this (simple) program from chapter 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math

def find_gcd(a,b):
    while b > 0:
        r = a - b * math.floor(a/b)
        a = b
        b = r
    return int(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import random, sys
    while True:
        print find_gcd(random.randrange(int(sys.argv[1])), random.randrange(int(sys.argv[2])))
```

...and just now I called it like so:

```
./gcd-rand.py 10000 10000 > concievablyreallyhugefile
```

...and now I'm dreaming of a `bash` one-liner that breaks when concievablyreallyhugefile has reached a certain size. I guess it would look something like:

```
while $(du -h f) < 32M; do ./gcd-rand.py 10000 10000 > $f; done
```

...but I have never written a while loop in `bash` before and I don't really know how the syntax works.

Comment: To answer your question you don't need to buy a book, actually — just issue `man bash`.

Comment: I presume the exercise you're working through asks you to roll your own, but for the sake of reference, the [`fractions.gcd` method](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd) is useful.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use the test command `test` or the equivalent `[ ... ]`:

```
 while [ "$(du -m f|cut -f1)" -lt 32 ]
 do 
  ./gcd-rand.py 10000 10000 > "$f"
 done
```

See `help test` for more information.

**Note**

`test` or `[` command is a bash *builtin*. The help information can be retrieved inside bash via `help test` or `help [`.
`man test` refers to the `test` command that is used if a shell has no such *builtin* or is invoked explicitly as `/usr/bin/test`.

Comment: `man test` you meant(?)

Comment: No - see the added Note in the answer.

Comment: Huh. `help` is a Bash-builtin but not `zsh`'s, for e. g.

Answer (score 3):

```
./gcd-rand.py 10000 10000 | head -c 32M > concievablyreallyhugefile
```

`head` will stop reading after 32MB. Soon after `head` stops reading, `gcd-rand.py` will receive a [SIGPIPE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29964/are-linux-utilities-smart-when-running-piped-commands/30011#30011) signal and exit.

To avoid storing a truncated last line, as [Michael Kjörling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67175/bash-while-loop-that-breaks-at-a-given-file-size/67271?noredirect=1#comment97278_67271) noticed:

```
./gcd-rand.py 10000 10000 | head -c 32M | sed '$d' > concievablyreallyhugefile
```

Comment: This. Piping is The Unix Way (tm), *and* it will give you exactly as much data as you want. Of course, it *might* break the resulting file in the middle of a number, so in the general case the last line of the file will be meaningless. If you want to guard against that, it'd probably be better to implement output size limiting in the script itself (look up `len()`, and remember to account for the newline).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Good point about the last truncated line. Again piping saves the day.

Answer (score 1):

Your python code loops forever. Thus, you might want to run it in the background and then kill it when the file size is exceeded. As one-liner:

```
{ ./gcd-rand.py 10000 10000 > f & }; p=$!; while (( $(stat -c %s f) < 33554432 )); do sleep .1; done; kill $p
```

Note: choose sleep time as appropriate, instead of stat you can also use du, as suggested by Dirk.

Comment: This is good, but you should use `wc -c` instead of `stat`, which will allow it to work outside of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ulimit` command to restrict how large a file the shell (or its children) can create:

```
ulimit -f 32768
```

Comment: I think this qualifies as an excellent example of what [Raymond Chen calls "using global state to manage a local problem"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx).

Comment: Well, it's limited to the current shell, so `(ulimit -f 32768; cmd)` is a possibility.