# Process does not close on broken pipe

Tags: ubuntu, process, pipe

I am starting following command from a bash script (arguments omitted for simplicity)

```
avconv | sox | nc
```

I am starting about 150 such commands on the same box at the same time.

The last `nc` command sends the stream to another host. When that host dies, `nc` dies but `avconv` and `sox` can stay alive. When I then `killall sox` in this situation, `avconv` stays alive.

Should there not be a `sigpipe`?

When I execute the bash script manually and `nc` dies, the other two processes die too. But not when I start many such scripts .

Is it possible that `sigpipe` does not work when pipe buffers are full or the system is otherwise highly contended? How can I work around it?

Comment: If the `nc` program goes away, the `sox` program will only get a `sigpipe` when the `sox` tries to write some data to the pipe. So `sox` needs to be outputting data. `sox` probably buffers output, so it might need to output several thousand characters before it actually tries to push the data through the pipe.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29964/are-linux-utilities-smart-when-running-piped-commands/29970 is related

Comment: Is there a way to bind their lifetimes together? I want all processes to terminate if one terminates.

Comment: or is there a way to kill the parent process when no data flows through the pipe for some time? Example usage: `avconv | sox | check-data-flow-or-kill-parent | nc`

Comment: Of course you can bind the lifetimes together. The question is do you want to? For example if sox exits before nc has sent out its data do you want it to exit, dropping the unsent information? Certainly one could write a check-data-flow-or-kill-parent, it is not hard. One caveat is that the parent may not be what you think it is, it depends on which shell creates the pipeline. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Would doing `killall avconv` solve your problem? If avconv goes away then sox will get eof on its input, and probably will exit, then nc will get eof...

Comment: This is for a system that records a stream from the internet, converts it and sends it off to another host in a "best effort" way. It's totally okay for the whole chain to terminate if one process terminates and there is unprocessed data. If there is an issue with either conversion, the destination host or otherwise, some loss is unavoidable and acceptable. I just need the chain to fail fast when there is an issue. 

killall is not an option because I have 150 parallel instances of it. If one instance of `nc` has an issue, the other instances don't necessarily need to have an issue.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve: I have a retry mechanism for the `avconv | sox | nc` chain. I want the chain to restart doing its work whenever there is any problem with any of the 3 processes. Unfortunately when the destination host goes down, I see many instances of `avconv` and `sox` still up, although `nc` is terminated. For that reason, my retry mechanism has no effect because some child processes are still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will kill the process group when the nc ends

```
#!/bin/sh
avconv x y z | sox a b c | { nc somewhere port ; pkill -g 0 ; }
```

Depending on how this gets started you might need to use a utility like setsid to restrict the things which are in the group. You could also replace `-g 0` with `-P $$`. This works by the shell running the pkill command after the nc finishes.

See also [Kill all descendant processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124127/kill-all-descendant-processes/124130)

Comment: `pkill -g 0` seemed to somehow kill the parent's parent process too. `pkill -P $$` worked wonderfully! Thanks!